# GreenDao how to filter data and retrieve it

Tags: android, database, calendar, android-sqlite, greendao

I have a table with entries such as:

```
private Long id;
private String Date;
private String Time;
private String newEntry;
private String description;
private byte[] images;
```

I use this for a calendar and I want it to display only entries from that day. How do I go about doing that?

Currently it retrieves all the entries and displays it ina listview:

```
List<Box> list = BoxRepository.getAllBoxes(getApplicationContext());
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Size = " + list.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    arrayEntry.clear();
    for (Box box : list)
        arrayEntry.add(box);
    adapterEntry.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

My guess was that I could add a method here but I failed:

```
public static long insertOrUpdate(Context context, Box box) {
    return getBoxDao(context).insertOrReplace(box);
}

public static void clearBoxes(Context context) {
    getBoxDao(context).deleteAll();
}

public static void deleteBoxWithId(Context context, long id) {
    getBoxDao(context).delete(getBoxForId(context, id));
}

public static List<Box> getAllBoxes(Context context) {
    return getBoxDao(context).loadAll();
}

public static Box getBoxForId(Context context, long id) {
    return getBoxDao(context).load(id);
}

private static BoxDao getBoxDao(Context c) {
    return ((DatabaseManager) c.getApplicationContext()).getDaoSession().getBoxDao();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what's your question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JofreMateu I'm trying to filter the database by it's date and populate my list but I couldn't.

Comment: You should use a QueryBuilder if you want to filter the query results. If you attach the Box entity structure I could help you with the code.

Comment: @JofreMateu I'm guessing this is what you asked for [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kesp0cjay730ja4/Box.java?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't now how you format the date, but it should be something like that:

```
helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this, "your database", null);
db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
boxDao= daoSession.getBoxDao();
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = boxDao.queryBuilder()
    .where(BoxDao.Properties.Date.eq("something to compare"));
List<Box> list = queryBuilder.list();
```

Also, you could use the Date type for the Box.Date property in order to use the Date comparators:

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = boxDao.queryBuilder()
    .where(BoxDao.Properties.Date.eq(new Date()));
```

or

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = boxDao.queryBuilder()
    .where(BoxDao.Properties.Date.between(date1, date2));
```

Comment: Maybe I over-simplified it. I've extended the code, hope it helps.

Comment: thank you so much! Thank you for being patient. I works and I understand.